# Gibbs sampling in document clustering

Tags: clustering, sampling, inference, latent-variable, gibbs

I'm trying to understand the idea behind the Topic Models in document clustering. In Latent Dirichlet Allocation, it is necessary to approximate the posterior distribution of topics over the document. One of the methods is Gibbs sampling - I'm not sure if I understand how it works - I'm basing my understanding on this paper: http://faculty.washington.edu/jwilker/559/SteyversGriffiths.pdf.

It starts with random word-topic assignment and iteratively, new samples are computed, conditioned on previous results, and after some number of iterations, it starts to converge. But I don't really get the idea, why multiple samples need to be kept. Isn't the result of the last iteration the best approximation of the desired distribution?

I will be grateful for possibly very simple explanation - my knowledge in this area is really poor.